# Can I use log-log OLS with no constant to measrue the relationship between two variables in a non-normal distribution?

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, least-squares, nonparametric

I am trying to measure the relationship between the price of a futures-contract and the current price of the underlying asset on the day of purchasing said futures-contract. For this I have a dataset with daily data on both, amassing about 8000 observations, where 3500 of them have values for both variables.

The variable for the price of the underlying asset however, has a skewness of 5.3 and kurtosis of 44, because of some extreme values (i.e. p50 is 32, p99 is 185 and max is 462).

When log-transforming this, skewness and kurtosis changes to -0.5 and 7.12. And when doing a log-log regression without the constant, the coeficcient is 0.99 (0.98 R-sq, t=574). Is this a valid result to argument for the current price being very much connected to the price of the futures-contracts?

In that case, why does the non-transformed variables have a Pearson and Spearman's coef. of 0.5?

Comment: welcome to the site. Note that several popular software implementations of $R^2$ are unreliable when an intercept is not included. Can you also clarify why you don't want to include an intercept term? This is almost always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks.

I strayed away from the intercept term because I found it to not be logical in this situation. Since there is only one regressor and that one isn't categorical.

I.e. this is just a series of two prices, the constant would not give any meaningful insight. I was however not aware of how it might affect the R-sq.

Comment: I should mention however that when left in, the intercept is statistically significant.

Comment: use of an intercept term is disconnected from whether or not the data are categorical and also how many predictors there are. It seems to me like you want an intercept term in this model.

Comment: I see. If it is included it reduces the R-sq. to 0.26, and I feel that it doesn't do a lot to explain the relationship. Would there be any other tests that could prove to be more fitting in this instance?

How about using VAR and Granger's causality test on the non-transformed data?

Comment: Also, R-squared from a regression model with an incercept can be interpreted as the proportion of the variation of the dependent variable explained by the model. This is not the case if there is no intercept included. Meaning that R-squared values from the two types of models are not directly comparable.